# VB.NET spirograph program

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a a program that will draw hypotrochoids (spirograph). The program below compiles fine. But when I run it I only get a portion of the drawing.. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm fairly new to VB.. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW2fP.jpg

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim p As Integer
Dim x1 As Integer
Dim y1 As Integer
Dim x2 As Integer
Dim y2 As Integer

x = 75
y = 15
p = 15

x1 = (x + y) * Math.Cos(0) + p * Math.Cos(0)
y1 = (x + y) * Math.Sin(0) + p * Math.Sin(0)
For t = 0 To 500 Step 0.1
    x2 = (x + y) * Math.Cos(t) + p * Math.Cos((x + y) * t / y)
    y2 = (x + y) * Math.Sin(t) + p * Math.Sin((x + y) * t / y)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, x1, y1, x2, y2)
    x1 = x2
    y1 = y2
Next
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

The results of the Sin and Cos calculations result in negative numbers where the parameter is greater than 90 for cos and greater than 180 for sin.

To see the whole image, you need to change the offset for x2 and y2 - see the code below. Alter the number 200 in each of the four lines to a value appropriate for your picturebox

```
    x1 = 200 + CInt((x + y) * Math.Cos(0) + p * Math.Cos(0))
    y1 = 200 + CInt((x + y) * Math.Sin(0) + p * Math.Sin(0))

    For t As Double = 0 To 500 Step 0.1
        x2 = 200 + CInt((x + y) * Math.Cos(t) + p * Math.Cos((x + y) * t / y))
        y2 = 200 + CInt((x + y) * Math.Sin(t) + p * Math.Sin((x + y) * t / y))
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, x1, y1, x2, y2)
        x1 = x2
        y1 = y2
    Next
```